# Copy feature classes from feature datasets/geodatabases

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have two geodatabases that I would like to 'walk' through. They are  contained in a folder. Each feature dataset and feature class within the two gdbs have the same names.

[image: m]

What I really want is how to take the same two fc from the two gdbs so I can take them as as variables in an intersection process.

Here what I did, but it take the output in a new gdb and that take a space. Is there another way?

```
import os
import arcpy

input_fc_name = 'BuildingArea'
folder_of_gdbs = r'C:\GIS\updates'
output_gdb_path = r'C:\Users\S3GHA\OneDrive\المستندات\GIS\update_50k (1)\Update50k\output.gdb'

# assumes all gdbs are in folder_of_gdbs
input_gdbs = [g for g in os.listdir(folder_of_gdbs) if g.upper().endswith('.GDB')]

for gdb in input_gdbs:
arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(folder_of_gdbs, gdb)  # set workspace
out_fc_name = input_fc_name + '_' + os.path.splitext(gdb)[0]  # gets rid of extension (e.g ".gdb")
out_fc_path = os.path.join(output_gdb_path, out_fc_name)
arcpy.AddMessage(out_fc_name)
arcpy.management.Copy(input_fc_name, out_fc_path)
```

Comment: Given that one of several ways to do this is the ArcPy function called "walk", your Question doesn't display a great deal of research. You've tagged this with both Python and ModelBuilder; on which one do you want the Question to focus? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/walk.htm

Comment: @Vince I edit my question and make it more clear. thank you

Comment: Code should always be provided as text in the body of the Question.  Using images requires someone who wants to help to retype your code. It is NOT recommended to do geoprocessing on a externally mounted drive (slow and unreliable)

Comment: @Vince I edit it

Comment: This has a syntax error due to lack of indentation, just like the more and more duplicate Question asked two hours later.